# Am I sanitizing textarea safely

Tags: php, mysqli, xss, sanitization

I have been using this to sanitize my textareas from xss-injects, I havent had any problems yet but since I been reading around on google I am not sure if this is a safe way.

```
$comment = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));
```

Then I am inserting it to my DB using mysqli with bind_param(); to prevent sql-inject

And lasty I am just outputtting it by `<p><?php echo $info['comment']; ?></p>`

Is this a safe way?

What I want to do is just to is sanitize then store it in my DB then output it, with working linebreaks.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it as is, using the escaping that your database library provides.  `nl2br` and if needed `htlmentities/specialchars` when displaying it.

Comment: Cheers, any reason why not to use htmlspecialchars() right away when inserting into DB?

Comment: It is HTML, so if you want to render it as HTML it will be in its real form.  If you don't want it rendered as HTML then you would transform it.  It's not unsafe as HTML in the DB, but it could be unsafe rendered in a browser.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I dont have to worrie if I use `nl2br(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));`to insert, then just output it directly from DB since I already have done that sanitize since when I inserted it?

Comment: Store the actual input, not what's going to be displayed. This allows for easier editing, searching, less data saved, and much more that simply makes it best practice. Compare to: you can write all your code in one line if you want to, but why would you when there are better approaches?

Comment: @RobinCastlin to whom you are addressing your comment?

Comment: Thanks " This allows for easier editing, searching, less data saved" makes sense

Answer (score 1):

You're not sanitising at all.

As said, you need to use the escaping your database library provides, as the escaping methods vary depending on database type.

Historically, you'd use mysql_real_escape_string(), but that is now deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: Care to elaborate, rather than just being a douche-bag?

Comment: I am using mysqli bind_param/mysqli prepared statement so no need for real_escape?
My question is if the code above would protect me against XSS and not SQL-inject